# Integral of delta function times a multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, measure-theory

We define a function on a set of sets (in my especific case a sigma algebra) $$\delta_{x}(D)=1, \text{if $x\in D$}$$
and $0$ otherwise.

I'm having a hard time trying to understand the following integral:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\delta_{x_1}(D)h(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)dx_1dx_2...dx_n$$

I sort of reasoned that it should be $$\int_D\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}(h(x_1,...,x_n)dx_2...dx_n)dx_1$$

Would this be correct? If so what, would be the formal reasoning?

Comment: You should clarify your notation. The variable $x_1$ is overloaded if the symbol $\delta_{x_1}$ is meant to be a Dirac delta. Otherwise, if it is meant to be a partial derivative with respect to $x_1$, you should use $\partial_{x_1}h(x_1,\dots)$.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz sorry I do see how it was badly written, I have clarified some of the notation and made a correction on the result I came up with

Comment: On hindsight I believe it is obvios as the delta function will only be non zero on D and will be 1 there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first let's clarify some things. Let your function $h:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be absolutely integrable on the domain, i.e.
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |h(x_1, ..., x_n)| \;dx_1...dx_n < \infty
$$
and let your delta function be the Dirac delta, defined as a distribution through
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(x)f(x) \;dx = f(0).
$$

[Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) from measure theory then allows us to split your original integral due to the absolute integrability, i.e.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \delta(x_1)\cdot h(x_1, ..., x_n) \;dx_1...dx_n &= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(...\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}  \delta(x_1)\cdot h(x_1, ..., x_n) \;dx_1\right)...\right)\;dx_n\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(...\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}  h(0, x_2, ..., x_n) \;dx_2\right)...\right)\;dx_n\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} h(0, ..., x_n) \;dx_2...dx_n.
\end{align}
$$
Additionally, since Fubini's theorem tells us that the order of the split integrals does not matter, this would work for any $\delta(x_k), k\in1..n$, but I'll leave that proof as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Note that there might be a different reasoning, probably a theorem from real analysis, that would allow you to split the integral without the need for **absolute** integrability.